# How to protect high-bandwidth low-voltage lines from transients?

Tags: protection, zener, tvs

I've been using bidirectional TVS diodes for protecting a 2 Mbit single-ended 5V serial bus.
Unfortunately, the TVS-es I've been using have too high capacitance, and distort the shape of the bus so serial decode doesn't work.
Looking at data sheets, pretty much all of the low-voltage TVS-es have about 3 nF of capacitance at 5V stand-off / 6.5V break-down, or thereabouts. A representative data sheet is here:
http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/Files/Littelfuse/Technical%20Resources/Documents/Data%20Sheets/Littelfuse_TVS%20Diode_SA.pdf

3 nF is enough to distort the output waveform when the inputs connected to that capacitance are all high impedance, and the output is not super low impedance (an AVR microcontroller with a 70 Ohm current limiting resistor.) Quick calculator check says corner freqency of that RC circuit is about 750 kHz, so it sounds plausible that this is my problem.

So, what can I use to protect this bus?
Sub-questions:
- Is there some particular part/series of TVS that performs substantially better?
- Should I re-buffer the signal? (Unfortunately, I'm out of board space, and it'd be a pain to make more.)
- Would a small-signal Zener be "good enough" or not fast enough for transient protection?
- Or maybe Zeners have high capacitance, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to find the right part. For example, this [NUP2114](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NUP2114-D.PDF) TVS diode module has an advertised 0.8pF typical capacitance, and 1pF max. This module was designed for USB so it has 2 bi-directional data lines and 1 uni-directional line for the Vbus line, but you can find stand-alone bidirectional parts (or put 2 unidirectional parts in reverse bias) which meet your capacitance allowance.

Browsing quickly on Digikey brought up this [ESD9B5.0ST5G](http://www.onsemi.cn/pub_link/Collateral/ESD9B-D.PDF) single bi-directional TVS diode which has a typical 15pF capacitance.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just didn't use the right search terms. Our the good parts are not available in through-hole.